# Issue with tomcat restart of my application

Tags: java, tomcat6

While Deploying my app in tomcat its giving the below error and its not deploying myapp into tomcat webserver. It is happening frequently, and if we kill and restart again then its deploying myapp. Any reason for this fluctuations?

```
INFO: Deploying web application archive /usr/local/myapp/servers/tomcat-7/webapps/myapp.war
Oct 26, 2015 9:45:26 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase addChildInternal
SEVERE: ContainerBase.addChild: start:
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/myapp]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:649)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1081)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1877)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:439)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to complete the scan for annotations for web application [/myapp] due to a StackOverflowError. Possible root causes include a too low setting for -Xss and illegal cyclic inheritance dependencies. The class hierarchy being processed was [org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1EncodableVector->org.bouncycastle.asn1.DEREncodableVector->org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1EncodableVector]
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.checkHandlesTypes(ContextConfig.java:2126)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsStream(ContextConfig.java:2072)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsJar(ContextConfig.java:1947)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsUrl(ContextConfig.java:1913)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotations(ContextConfig.java:1898)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1330)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:889)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:386)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5380)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        ... 11 more
Oct 26, 2015 9:45:26 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
```

Comment: It detects stack overflow error and recommends to run tomcat with option `-Xss`. Have you tried it?

Comment: "illegal cyclic inheritance dependencies. The class hierarchy being processed was
[org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1EncodableVector-org.bouncycastle.asn1.DEREncodableVector-org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1EncodableVector] "

the error it showing is bounty castle jar and its related dependencies can you check those

Comment: Hi AlexR, How to run the tomcat with -Xss ?